# Strings not working in my function as parameters powershell

Tags: string, function, powershell, zip

```
function cee([string]$a,
[string]$b)
{
    Write-Host $a | ft
    $a.GetType()
    Write-Host $b | ft
    $b.GetType()
    Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    $compressionLevel = [System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel]::Optimal
    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($a,$b)
}
```

`cee('C:\FAKE','C:\zipfile.zip')`

When run in this manor it fails and errors with:

> C:\FAKE'C:\zipfile.zip
>
> IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
>   -------- -------- ----                                     --------
>   True     True     String                                   System.Object                                                         >
>
> True     True     String                                   System.Object
>   Exception calling "CreateFromDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "The given >path's format is not supported."
>   At line:10 char:9
>   +         [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory($a,
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~            + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException

If I store 'C:\FAKE\' and 'C:\zipfile.zip' as variables, manually running each line with the variables as input for $a and $b, it works just fine.

If I set [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)] , run the function, and enter 
C:\FAKE\
and 
C:\zipfile.zip at the prompt, it works just fine.

Comment: @PetSerAl What search terms did you use to locate the other answer? Clearly your search-fu is much better than mine. Or did knowing what I did wrong allow you to more easily find it? I would prefer to do a better job searching than bog down the community with duplicates.

Comment: I use `[powershell] parenthesis` in search. I is not my first time seeing this error in calling PowerShell function, so I already know what to search for.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thank you as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not correctly calling your function. You use a function as such:

```
cee 'C:\FAKE' 'C:\zipfile.zip'
```

Or more fully, by calling parameters by name:

```
cee -a 'C:\FAKE' -b 'C:\zipfile.zip'
```

Comment: Ah, yes, thank you. I knew my syntax had to be off somewhere. It has been interesting getting used to the way powershell does things.